# Navigation Bar Items not left aligned

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationbar

I have a `navigationBar` where I would like to have a `button` on the left, a `activityIndicator` as `title` and a `doneButton` on the right. This is what I tried:

```
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
    let googleImage  = UIImage(named: "google")!
    let googleButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: googleImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(googleButtonTapped))
    googleButton.image = UIImage(named: "google")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueCustom
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.color = .white
    
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.activityIndicator
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = googleButton
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Fertig", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneTapped))
```

The problem is that `googleButton` and `activityIndicator` are not on the left/center:

[image]

What am I missing here?

**Update:**

I tried setting the `leftBarButtonItem` to a simple item with `title` and it works as expexted.. Why is it not working with the image?

Comment: You initialize googleButton bar item with image, why you re-assign `googleButton.image` it later? Try to use `Debug View Hierarchy`

Comment: I fixed that but that didn't caused the issue. It is breaking several constriants at the navigationBar, but I don't know why

Comment: Can you share an image link to download it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the `intrinsicContentSize` of the `googleButton`. Since you haven't explicitly set it, the size of the google logo image is expanding the width of the button.  The `intrinsicContentSize` property of a `UIButton` has a set height by default, but none for the width:

```swift
let googleImage  = UIImage(named: "google")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal).resizeTo(size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
let googleButton = UIButton()
googleButton.setBackgroundImage(googleImage, for: .normal)
googleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(googleButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
let googleBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: googleButton)
```

You can create a UIImage extension to redraw the size of the google logo:

```swift
extension UIImage {
    func resizeTo(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        let image = renderer.image { _ in
            self.draw(in: CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
        }
        
        return image.withRenderingMode(self.renderingMode)
    }
}
```

Change the button name to:

```swift
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = googleBarButton
```

Of course, the 25 points for the width and the height is arbitrary. Adjust it to fit your need.